# How do I annul my vows?

Tags: nedarim-shevuot

I think there are things I’ve done three times and no longer do, or things I’ve committed to doing verbally, and I suspect they may have the status of a vow. How do I go about doing hataras nedarim on these actions? Do I need to gather three men and say something? English, Hebrew?? Do I need to specify each and every thing I’ve possibly vowed?

Comment: That is what we do every erev yom kippur

Answer (score 1):

The [Shulchan Arukh (Yoreh De'ah 228:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.228.1?lang=bi) writes:

> One who took a neder [sic: vow] and regrets it, can rectify the acceptance of the neder by having remorse. Even if one took a neder with the name of G-D. **What should that person do? They should go to a wise [Torah Scholar] who is an expert, who [is well versed in] learns logical inferences and deductive (talmudic) reasoning. If there is no expert, one should go to three average people.** These should be people who study with logical inferences and deductive reasoning, and who also know how to find loopholes; and they will release the vow. Nowadays there is no one considered to be an expert who is able to release a vow solely by themselves.

A bit further, the SA asks "How can you nullify a never?", on which it explains:

> You say three times "mutar lach" or "mochal lach" (you can say this in any language)

The Rambam in Mishneh Torah [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Oaths.6.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> How are oaths absolved? The person who took the oath should present himself to the distinguished scholar, or to three laymen if no expert is available, and say: "I took an oath concerning this and that, and now I am sorry. Had I known that I might be distressed because of it to such a degree, or that such a thing might happen to me, I would not have taken the oath. Had I known at the time of the oath what I know now, I would not have sworn." Thereupon the scholar, or the eldest of the three laymen, should say to him: "Have you regretted it indeed?" And he should reply: "Yes." Then he should say to him: "You are set free, you are pardoned," or anything similar in meaning in any language. If, however, he said to him: "Your oath is void," or "Your oath is eradicated," or something similar in meaning, what he said is of no avail, because none except a husband or a father can revoke an oath. A scholar may use only terms of absolution and pardon.

See also: [Hatarat Nedarim (Annulment of Vows)](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/15-05-11/) and the [Taz](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.228.3?lang=bi&with=Turei%20Zahav&lang2=en) on doing it in your own language (בכל לשון שיאמר)